# PHONE_STATE Intent-filter

Tags: android-intent

I need to find all applications that define the PHONE_STATE intent-filter in their manifest.. I got it working for the CALL-action string, so my code works:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, null);
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(callIntent, 0);
```

The problem is the String itself. It says [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) there is a constant Value "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE", but I can neither access it from code the way I did with the CALL-action string, neither can I define it in my own Manifest with

```
<intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
```

the way I did with the CALL-action string also, as in both situations, there is no such Value.
I have read about this intent in a paper [2] as well, so I am sure it did exist. So is it gone or can I access it in another way?
The reason I want to filter apps with that intent: I need all applications that registered a BoradcastReceiver for the PHONE_STATE action string and as far as I know this is done via that exact intent.
If it works differently now or if I got the string wrong, any hint is very much appreciated!

[2]: On Lightweight Mobile Phone Application Certification - Enck et al.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I read the link I've posted a few more times, and I was able to figure it out now. So here's the solution, if anyone else is confused about it as well:
It does not work the same way as for the other Intent for some reason.
AndroidStudio seems to have been confused as well, because I was able to add

```
<intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
```

into the Manifest this time.
You can then get it in your application with

```
Intent phoneStateIntent = new Intent(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
```

So the android-document posted above, it showed the connection between `TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` and the intent-filter `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`. I didn't realize that before!
Hope this helps someone else!